# Table or gridlayout in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I want to display 3 rows on the screen for which table or gridlayout is needed.
Is it possible without using frameworks?
How should I implement for displaying 3 rows on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use existing GUI libraries that help you use XML, CSS etc. to do layout. One site to check out this:

http://www.newsofthefuture.net/index.php?/archives/33-Evaluation-GUI-libraries-for-J2ME.html

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Table or gridlayout in J2ME you should create your own item with the help of CustomItem (javax.microedition.lcdui.CustomItem). You should code for drawing lines for rows and columns.

If you use NetBeans then in NetBeans Mobility Pack there is library used for displaying a table. If you use NetBeans then you use the "org.netbeans.microedition.lcdui.TableItem" for the table.