# How can I have two items next to eachother, in a row, on a form?

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

```
            Form containerForm=new Form(filename);

            StringItem label1 = new StringItem("","Test\nTest2\nTest3");
            StringItem label2 = new StringItem("","Test\nTest2\nTest3");

            label2.setLayout(Item.LAYOUT_LEFT|Item.LAYOUT_TOP|Item.LAYOUT_SHRINK  );
            label2.setLayout(Item.LAYOUT_RIGHT|Item.LAYOUT_TOP|Item.LAYOUT_SHRINK );


            containerForm.append(label1);
            containerForm.append(label2);

            display.setCurrent(containerForm);
```

This code produces this:

[image]

I want it so the two StringItems are next to eachother, and test is lined up with test, and so on.

I've also tried combining the two stringitems into one and adding a tab (\t) between them. The tab turned into nothing, however.

Answer (score 1):

if you're on MIDP 2 it would be safer to also set `LAYOUT_2` in addition to directives you already have set. Per my recollection of API spec, without this flag device may (or maybe even should) fall to MIDP 1 layout style ignoring your precious `TOP` and `SHRINK`.

Consider also using `Item.setPreferredWidth(containerForm.getWidth()/3)` to explicitly indicate that you want it to be not too wide. There seem to be small (but non-zero) chance that stupid device believes that preferred width of your string items is that of the screen which in turn somehow *overrules* shrink directive.

Answer (score 0):

Java ME uses a row layout, which means every item you add is added in the next row of the GUI. You need something like a GridLayout which is not available in Java ME. Maybe you have to write your own Item which contains both labels. Similar to [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/customitems/index.html). Here is a stackoverflow question on Gridlayouts in Java ME: [Table or gridlayout in J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920847/table-or-gridlayout-in-j2me)

Answer (score 0):

Use the GridLayout using LWUIT

http://lwuit.java.net/tutorial/layouts.html